# check exit code using if condition in expect enviroment

Tags: linux, bash, expect

i'm trying to do something simple using expect but no luck.
after connection the remote server using ssh i just try to see if a directory
is exist or not by checking the command exit code:

```
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no $buildUser@$buildServer
expect "*?assword:*"
send "mdusr1\r"
expect "*?>"
send "ls $buildPath\r"
expect "*?>"
if { $? -eq 0 } {
send_user "Done"
}
```

this code fails with the following error:

```
ls: /d: No such file or directory
xxx@yyy> missing operand at _@_
in expression " 0 -_@_eq 0 "
    (parsing expression " 0 -eq 0 ")
    invoked from within
"if { 0 -eq 0 }"
```

Can someone please advise what is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Shell variables aren't available in expect, all its gets is the output. You need to send a command that prints the value of `$?`, then read it in.

Answer (score 0):

this is a tcl syntax error. 
See http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm , also http://wiki.tcl.tk/1042 and of course http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect .

Edit:
now I have acces to a machine with expect. here is an actually working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /bin/bash
expect "$ "
send "ls file/you/are/looking/for\r"
expect "$ "
send "echo $?\r"
expect "\n"
expect -re "\[0-9]"
set re $expect_out(buffer)
if {$re eq 0} {
    send_user "\nfound\n"
} else {
    send_user "\nnot found\n"
}
```

Comment: sorry but still failing with error:  wrong # args: no script following " 0 eq 0 " argument
    while executing
"if { 0 eq 0 }"

Comment: you did not delete the trailing "{", did you?
http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm

Comment: There must be a space between `}` and `{` -- Tcl is word-oriented and whitespace really matters. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you are spawned into a shell, you can let the shell handle it:

```
send "[ -f \"$buildPath\" ] && echo found || echo not found\r"
```